# Too Many Included SPF Lookups

Tags: domains, dns, email, spf

I used a [DNS lookup tool](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3Aalexcapmusic.com&run=toolpage) on my website and did an SPF record lookup as well and discovered that I have "too many included lookups." I understand the limit is 10, but it looks to me like I'm only using 6 (mx, and 5 includes). The tool says I'm using 23. How is this possible?

If you understand how I'm using too many lookups, how can I reduce this to within the limit and optimize my spf record?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to pare it down quite a bit. Is it better to use IP addresses of mail servers or includes (or both)? If IP addresses are better, how can I find out the IP address of the server that I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SPF record (DNS `TXT`) looks currently like:

```
"v=spf1 mx include:_spf.google.com include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:servers.mcsv.net ~all"
```

It had previously a direct include of `office365.com`,
and the include statements can be recursive. The client needs to follow all of them. So you may have only 5, but some induce other includes... Like `office365.com` for example that has `include:spf.protection.outlook.com`. Are you sure you need yourself so many includes? Are you sure you will **send** emails on behalf of your domain from all these providers?

In the same way, `gmail.com` SPF has a redirect to `_spf.google.com` which itself has 3 include. Just with all that you have already 5 DNS queries. And that is only for one of 5 includes you have.

As for the additional question about "is it better to use IP addresses of mail servers or includes (or both)?":
the problem with IP addresses is that you do not control which ones are the correct ones as you rely on external providers. So if you use them you are dependent on them not changing, or you monitoring them out of band, or asking your provider to notify you of the correct ones. So includes are probably simpler for a management perspective but then as you saw you have other problems with the other limits of the protocol.